# Issue calling a HorizontalScrollView.getRight() within an ListView's onItemClickListener.

Tags: android, scrollview, onitemclicklistener

I have a HorizontalScrollView which contains a variable number of VISIBLE or GONE ListViews.

When a ListView's OnItemClickListener is called, part of the handling code changes the visibility of other ListViews.

As part of the OnItemClickListener I am trying to HorizontalScrollView.scrollTo() to show newly visible ListViews at the right hand side of the ScrollView.

scrollView.getRight() does not report a changed size of the scrollView's content after ListViews are made VISIBLE or GONE.  It does report the correct new content size after the OnItemClickListener has returned.

Is there some form of OnReflowed callback that I've missed?

How can I do a .getRight() as soon as the layout is reflowed, after the OnItemClickListener has exited?

Comment: use the famous OnGlobalLayoutListener http://www.sherif.mobi/2013/01/how-to-get-widthheight-of-view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to:

1) insert a subclassed the (linear) layout between the ScrollView and the ListViews

2) add an onSizeChanged method to the subclass:

```
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    ((HorizontalScrollView) getParent()).scrollTo(w, 0);
}
```